# Question about IM/LS model and aggregate demand/supply

Tags: macroeconomics

[image]

IS curve assumes aggregate demand equals production. Together with LM curve, for a particular price and other exogenous variables, we have one set of production and interest rate that balances both markets.

The picture above shows the aggregate demand and supply curves. Aggregate demand curve comes from varying the price variable and printing all the different balance productions out into the graph. Aggregate supply is exogenous.

For a given price, it can be seen in the graph that the aggregate demand (equal to production as is the premise of the IS curve) is not equal to aggregate supply. Hence I can only assume that aggregate supply and production are different things. What is the difference? If they are the same, what am I missing, and can someone clarify my gaps in understanding?

Thanks in advance.